# Wordpress site down after leadpage plugin installation

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress site and when updating a leadpages plugin, I am seeing the following error...

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home2/dhankaran/public_html/wp-content/plugins/leadpages/App/Bootstrap/AdminBootstrap.php on line 196

I don't know where this file resides so I cannot update the code. please help!

Thanks
DK

Comment: The error tells you where there file is '/home2/dhankaran/public_html/wp-content/plugins/leadpages/App/Bootstrap/AdminBootstrap.php'

Comment: thanks @ButchMonkey .. I do see that but i cannot update the files for some reason. I ended up going to the wordpress cname and reverting the change from there.

Answer (score 0):

Switch your display errors OFF from cpanel or wp-config.php, This may be the issue...

```
// Write this code in wp-config.php
// log php errors
@ini_set('log_errors','On'); // enable or disable php error logging (use 'On' or 'Off')
@ini_set('display_errors','Off'); // enable or disable public display of errors (use 'On' or 'Off')
```

Also check wp_debug in wp-config.php

```
 define('WP_DEBUG', false); // disable debugging mode
```

Comment: thanks Hritik Pandey .. I ended up going to the wordpress cname and reverting the change from there.